# Stop Subclipse from displaying revision information beside file name

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, navigation, subclipse

I am using Eclipse PDT and the navigator view and I am wondering: Is it possible to stop Subclipse from displaying revision information beside file name?

e.g. Turn:

```
.buildpath 6 04/09/10 9:25 AM Lemiant
```

Into

```
.buildpath
```

I would still like to be able to access the information, I just don't need it cluttering of the navigator,

Thanks,

Lemiant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to configure the exact amount of label decoration you want in the **[Subclipse settings](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/topics/preferences.html)**:

[image]